# Outlook Restore

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Recently one of my friend's Windows XP's hard drive crashed. I have the drive hooked up through a SATA to USB cable right now and I'm trying to find the Outlook or Outlook Express data file. I'm not sure which client she used. I checked the Documents and Settings/username/Local Settings/Application Data/Microsoft/Outlook and nothing was there. Is there any way to find out the default path to the .pst file or is there a tool to find a .pst file? I tried windows search for *.pst and it only found a backup.pst file in a public folder that was extremely old. Does anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE**: now I know it's Outlook.

Comment: Well, now I know it's Outlook.

Comment: So, did this solve your question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tell it to search hidden and system files?

If it is a POP3/IMAP then it will be using a PST.

The only other storage format for Outlook is OST when caching with Exchange, in which case you would have no need to restore

Comment: ahh, i always thought it was defaulted to search hidden locations. Didn't see that option near that annoying dog. Trying it now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was the user using exchange? If so you would need to find the *.ost file, not a *.pst file. Of course, if this is the case you wouldn't really need to worry about it since the mail would be on the server. Outlook express uses *.dbx files to store mail so you could search for them as well if, as you mention, you think that may have been what the client used.